# C# How to get properties value of generic class at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, runtime

How to get value and type of "strx" at runtime? Cant get value of cell (properties) at runtime when using generics (as result of under code is "null").

Example

```
   public class Foo 
    {
        public int x, y;
        public string strx, stry;
    }

    public void GetCellValueByName<T>(GridView gridview, string name/)
    {
        T = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        object row = gridview.GetRow(gridview.GetSelectedRows()[0]);

        if (row != null && row is T) 
        {
            columnType = (T)gridview.GetRow(gridview.GetSelectedRows()[0]);
            PropertyInfo info = columnType.GetType().GetProperty(name);
            if (info != null) 
            {  // Here I got always null
                info.GetValue(columnType, null);
            }
        }
    }

string valueOfStrx = GetCellValueByName<Foo>(grid, "strx");
```

Comment: Can you please clean up the code of your sample. As it is, it is really hard to read because - as far I understand it - it contains several lines that are not necessary. Also, variable names like *type* and *typ* are easily mixed up. The chances to get a good answer are much higher if your code is easy to understand.

Comment: If you're adding custom objects to a DataGridView why aren't you accessing the values through the data-binding itself? This seems like it is over complicating something that is simple but hard to gather what the purpose is because of the lack of context.

Comment: @Markus - hi can you see updated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in class `Foo`, `strx` is a field (member variable):

```
public string strx, stry;
```

In your method, you try to use `GetProperty`, but this will not find the field:

```
PropertyInfo info = columnType.GetType().GetProperty(name);
```

So either change the member to a property

```
public string strx { get; set; }
public string stry { get; set; }
```

or use `GetField` instead:

```
FieldInfo info = columnType.GetType().GetField(name);
// ...
info.GetValue(columnType); // Note that GetValue for a field does not take a second parameter
```